# How do I get the number of days in the month specified by an elisp time?

Tags: emacs, date, elisp

In elisp I have a time in the (form of three integers), and I can get the month using decode-time. What I'd like to get is the number of days in that month (and year), using elisp functions (rather than write my own).

i.e:

```
(defun days-in-month-at-time(t)
    ; Figure out month and year with decode-time
    ; return number of days in that month   
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(require 'timezone)

(defun days-in-month-at-time (time)
  "Return number of days in month at TIME."
  (let ((datetime (decode-time time)))
    (timezone-last-day-of-month (nth 4 datetime) (nth 5 datetime))))
```

Comment: Also see related SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753248/insert-whole-month-of-dates-in-emacs-lisp

Comment: timezone-last-day-of-month is not present on my work machine Windows build of emacs 23.1.1 I wonder if it's been removed, or added after that?

Comment: Ah, I see, you need to load or require calendar (or timezone), hence the apparent difference.

Comment: @justinhj: you're right, neither `calendar` or `timezone` loaded by default, so you may need require the package first.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is better since time-zone doesn't seem to be in all recent emacs versions
edit: Sorry you just need to require timezone, or calendar depending on whether you use this or the other answer.

```
(defun days-in-month-at-time (time)
  "Return number of days in month at TIME."
  (let ((datetime (decode-time time)))
    (calendar-last-day-of-month (nth 4 datetime) (nth 5 datetime))))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in emacs 22.1.1 on Mac: (days-in-month-at-time (current-time))

Comment: I think you need (require 'calendar) first.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that doesn't require `timezone` or `calendar` by extracting the day from the last day of the month:

```
(defun days-in-month-at-time(tm)
  (let ((d (decoded-time-add (decode-time tm) (make-decoded-time :month 1))))
    (setf (decoded-time-day d) 1)
    (decoded-time-day (decoded-time-add d (make-decoded-time :day -1))))
  )
```